# Searching Lync Centralized Logging Using Time

Tags: lync-2013, centralized-logging

This is my first attempt to use the Centralized Logging Service to try to generate some logs for a problem a user is having, so perhaps I'm not doing something right.  I'm using the commands below to start, stop and search the CLS, but every time I include a StartTime in the Search-CsClsLogging command it returns nothing.

This is the command I'm running to start the logging:
`Start-CsClsLogging -Pools 'pool01.domain.com','pool02.domain.com','edgepool01.domain.com','edgepool02.domain.com' -Scenario IncomingAndOutgoingCall -Duration 0.00:15`

This is the command I'm running to stop the logging:
`Stop-CsClsLogging -Pools 'pool01.domain.com','pool02.domain.com','edgepool01.domain.com','edgepool02.domain.com' -Scenario IncomingAndOutgoingCall`

This is the command I'm running to search the logging:
`Search-CsClsLogging -StartTime '7/20/2016 14:08:50' -EndTime '7/20/2016 14:12:51' -LogLevel All -OutputFilePath 'C:\logfile.txt'`

I run the commands in that order Start, Stop, Search.  When I include the StartTime parameter I always get no results returned.  The documentation says the time should be in local time, which it is, but I've also tried using UTC and that doesn't work either.  If I don't include the StartTime I get the log file written to.

Am I running these command incorrectly?  I cannot see why including the time continually yields a blank output file.

Comment: What about `-StartTime '7/20/2016 2:08:50PM' -EndTime '7/20/2016 2:12:51PM'` ?

Comment: Well I feel stupid.  This worked.  I thought I'd tried that, but apparently I only tried it when using the UTC time not the local time. Thanks!  If you want to add it as answer, I'll mark it as such

Comment: ok done, answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to not be clearly mentionned in the doc (or i missed it - or i may be wrong), but given exemples make me think you need to specify date/time using 12 hours format with AM/PM, but not 24 hours format.

So, your filter will look like this :

```
-StartTime '7/20/2016 2:08:50PM' -EndTime '7/20/2016 2:12:51PM'
```